# Deprecated configuration property 'spring.datasource.initialization-mode'

Tags: spring-boot

This is going to be the spring back-end of a project that I am working on. I am able to create tables from my model classes in Postgres database however I wasn't able to put static data to the tables.

I created a data.sql file in resources with bunch of insert commands.

This is how my application.properties looks like:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springtest
spring.datasource.username= 
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create 
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

The compiler(Intellij) is crossing a line over

> "spring.datasource.initialization-mode"

with the message:

> Deprecated configuration property
> 'spring.datasource.initialization-mode'

It also suggest me to use the replacement key `spring.sql.init.mode=always` however this does not work as well. I need the program to execute the SQL commands in data.sql.

Comment: With `spring.sql.init.mode` set to `always` SQL commands in `schema.sql` and `data.sql` should be executed automatically.  Can you update your question with a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve) so we can figure out why that’s not happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Spring Boot 2.5.0 by default, `data.sql` scripts are now run before Hibernate is initialized. This aligns the behavior of basic script-based initialization with that of Flyway and Liquibase. If you want to use `data.sql` to populate a schema created by Hibernate, set `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization` to `true`.
Additional info: [github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out by changing

> spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

to

> spring.sql.init.mode=always

and renaming `data.sql to import.sql`

Comment: A file named `import.sql` is processed by Hibernate and is unaffected by any `spring.sql.init.*` properties.